# C++20 Concepts: Element iterable concept

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I am trying to create a concept `ElementIterable` which can determine the type is nested ranges or not. For example, the elements in `std::vector<int>` is not iterable, but the elements (`std::vector<int>`) in `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` is iterable. The idea about using `std::iterator_traits<T>` comes up in my mind and the experimental code is as following. However, this `ElementIterable` concept doesn't work as the expected behavior. Is there any idea to fix this `ElementIterable` concept?

```
template<typename T>
concept ElementIterable = requires(typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type x)                        //  requires-expression
{
    x.begin();          // must have `x.begin()`
    x.end();            // and `x.end()`
};
```

The usage of this `ElementIterable` is here.

```
template<typename T> requires ElementIterable<T>
void Foo(T input);

template<typename T> requires ElementIterable<T>
void Foo(T input)
{
    std::cout << "Element iterable" << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void Foo(T input);

template<typename T>
void Foo(T input)
{
    std::cout << "Element not iterable" << std::endl;
}
```

The usage of the function `Foo`.

```
int number = 1;
    
std::vector<decltype(number)> vector1;
vector1.push_back(number);
Foo(vector1);           //  Element not iterable

std::vector<decltype(vector1)> vector2;
vector2.push_back(vector1);
Foo(vector2);           //  Element not iterable
                        //      but expected behaviour is: Element iterable
```

All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Why not simply check for `v.begin()->begin()` and `v.end()->end()` on the type itself, `T`?

Comment: I think this question title should be renamed to be more verbose. Beginners are searching for a concept which simply checks if something is iterable, which is built in via std::ranges::range, but are instead finding this specialised concept instead. Searching "c++ iterable concept" puts this question at the top.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to ask if a type is a range which itself contains a range, that's simply applying the `std::range` type twice:

```
template<typename T>
concept nested_range = std::ranges::range<T> && std::ranges::range<std::ranges::range_value_t<T>>
```

`range_value_t` extracts the `value_type` from the iterator type of the range. [Here's a live example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/bPbqed).

Answer (score 8):

Well, the problem is `std::iterator_traits<T>`. The argument for `iterator_traits` is supposed to be an iterator type. Meanwhile, you want the concept to be applicable unto containers. Since `std::iterator_traits` is designed to be SFINAE friendly, and it's unlikely a container will satisfy enough of the legacy iterator concept, it's more than likely `std::iterator_traits<T>` has no members when you check your concept. That leads to the concept not being satisfied.

Why not rely on the concepts in the ranges header? It has a handy utility to obtain the value type of a type that satisfies the range concept

```
#include <ranges>

template<typename T>
concept ElementIterable = requires(std::ranges::range_value_t<T> x)
{
    x.begin();          // must have `x.begin()`
    x.end();            // and `x.end()`
};
```

Or, slightly more robust and without reinventing standard traits

```
template<typename T>
concept ElementIterable = std::ranges::range<std::ranges::range_value_t<T>>;
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of the reason why `std::iterator_traits<T>` can't take effect.

Answer (score 5):

C++20 concepts can be as dumb (as in, text replacing) as you need them to be. In your case, simple template duck typing should do the job by checking for what you need to exist, ie iterator functions in the results of your type's iterator functions.

With that in mind, you can try something like this:

```
template<typename T>
concept ElementIterable = requires(T x)
{
    x.begin()->begin();        
    x.end()->end();            
};
```

Comment: Yeah fixed it, was a left-over from copying the provided code

Comment: This is a pretty poor concept. It doesn't use any existing standard library concepts, and thus can't subsume them. All it checks for is the presence of *memberwise* `begin/end`, not `ranges::begin/end` which allows for other things. Overall, this just isn't a good way to resolve the issue.